# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzat.class

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1 and I'm getting a gradle build error.

build.gradle > add library > compile files('libs/tnkad-sdk.jar')

After trying to build, I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':plup:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.  
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzat.class
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbn.class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718274/com-android-build-api-transform-transformexception-java-util-zip-zipexception)

Answer (score 0):

Add latest version of play services.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
```