# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzel.class

Tags: android, gradle

This is my gradle file.. I'm getting this issue

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':crushmatic:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/android/gms/internal/zzel.class

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'

        lintOptions {

            checkReleaseBuilds false
            // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
            // but continue the build even when errors are found:
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

    dexOptions {    
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"    
    }

    defaultConfig {    
        applicationId "com.crushmatic.pro"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    android {    
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }

    repositories {    
        maven {
            url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"    
        }    
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }    
}
```

My Dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':rangeBar')
    compile project(':seekArc_library')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':zoomimage')
    compile files('libs/android-query.0.25.10.jar')
    compile files('libs/asmack-android-8.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/eventbus-2.1.0-beta-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.3.jar')
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.1'
    compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.8.5.jar');

    compile files('libs/picasso-2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/sinch-android-rtc-3.9.8.jar')

    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.3.0'
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')    
}
```

Could anyone help me to fix this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult)

Comment: check any duplicate library or old version using or not

Comment: There is no duplicate library..Can you please help me to fix this

Comment: First of all: convert your `.jar` dependencies to gradle dependencies. You have not and that is why you have a problem. Then run in console the command to check dependencies.

Comment: sorry, I am a beginner. How to convert .jar  dependencies to gradle dependencies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbn.class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718274/com-android-build-api-transform-transformexception-java-util-zip-zipexception)

Comment: you are use same functionality provided library, so check and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command at the Android Studio Terminal:

**1**

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies
```

**2**

```
./gradlew clean (Android ---> Clean the Project)
```

**3**

```
./gradlew clean assembleDebug | ./gradlew clean:assembleDebug
```

With this things that you wrote you are cleaning and rebuilding the project. Specifically with the first one you are deleting everything duplicate and wrong in your project.

Let me know if this works! I fixed my project.